# Getting error "The rollback transaction request has no corresponding begin transaction"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a trigger and for some reason the second if statement breaks my code.

If I delete the second if statement the code will work. The error that I am getting is:

> The rollback transaction request has no corresponding begin transaction

My code:

```
create trigger insertemployee 
on jobinsailing 
after insert 
as 

BEGIN TRANSACTION   

declare @sailingID        int, 
        @employeeID       char(9), 
        @jobTitle         varchar(10), 
        @sailingStartDate date, 
        @sailingEndDate   date 

select @sailingId = inserted.sailingid, 
       @employeeID = inserted.employeeid, 
       @jobTitle = inserted.jobtitle, 
       @sailingStartDate = sailing.leavingtime, 
       @sailingEndDate = sailing.returntime 
from   inserted 
       inner join sailing 
               on inserted.sailingid = sailing.sailingid 

if exists(select employeeid 
          from   sailing 
                 inner join jobinsailing 
                         on sailing.sailingid = jobinsailing.sailingid 
          where  ( @sailingStartDate <= returntime ) 
                 and ( leavingtime <= @sailingEndDate ) 
                 and employeeid = @employeeID) rollback TRANSACTION; 


else if exists((select sailing.sailingid 
          from   sailing 
                 inner join jobinsailing 
                         on jobinsailing.sailingid = sailing.sailingid 
          where  Datediff(day, @sailingStartDate, sailing.leavingtime) <= 4 
                  or Datediff(day, @sailingEndDate,sailing.leavingtime) <= 4 
                  or Datediff(day, @sailingStartDate,sailing.returntime) <= 4 
                  or Datediff(day, @sailingEndDate,sailing.returntime) <= 4
                  ))  rollback TRANSACTION;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Not related to your error, but you do realise your trigger is broken? In SQL Server the `inserted` pseudo-table will contain as many rows as have been inserted which could be more than 1. You have to write triggers to handle this case else you will get some very nasty behaviour when a multi-row insert happens.

Comment: The other thing is that triggers run within an implied transaction, you don't normally need to start a new one. You can still call rollback on the external transaction (which rewinds the insert probably as you are wanting to do).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. At first I didn't write the begin transaction and still got the same error

Comment: Remove the begin trans AND the commit. There are a load of questions on this over at dba... e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86058/xact-abort-off-vs-commit-in-trigger

Comment: You say the second if statement is causing the issue. Why not combine the two if statements with and `OR` condition. e.g. `IF EXISTS(....) OR EXISTS( ... ) ROLLBACK`.

Answer (score 0):

## Conditional Insert

What you are trying to achieve is to conditionally insert records into a table using a trigger.

This is generally a bad approach. Your code (Stored Procedures and/or business tier code) should determine if the record should be inserted first before inserting it. Triggers are not the best tool for this - they are meant to allow you to enforce complex constraints.

Assuming that you must use triggers, then I suggest you use `INSTEAD OF` triggers. They are designed to override the default insert process that normally occurs and allow you to insert (or not insert) data, rather than having to rollback transactions.

### Multi Row Insert

As @DaleBurrell has pointed out, trigger is executed once per insert operation and `inserted` table can contain multiple rows. It is best practice to code your triggers such that they allow multi row operations but you can also enforce single row operations by adding this line to the top of your trigger `IF (ROWCOUNT_BIG() > 1) ROLLBACK`.

### Further reading

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/creating-insert-triggers-silently-ignore-data-dont-want/
- http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-instead-of-trigger/

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but it doesn't  look like that you solved my problem. I must use a trigger for this exercise.

Comment: I have suggested that you use `INSTEAD OF` triggers (they are easy to implement, if you follow examples in links), then you do not have to have rollback transaction statements and the corresponding error handling mess. As far as giving the actual code solution - I can't make sense of your code, so I prefer not to guess.

Comment: i am not looking for a way around this problem. I want to find the bug for the current code.

Comment: 1. You do not need `BEGIN TRANSACTION ` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION`. 2. Are you sure you do not rollback a transaction outside the trigger? I am unable to reproduce the error message. Please include full code, including how you insert into your table.

Comment: do you want the DB code as well? this is the full code

Comment: Please provide a sample insert statement that causes the error.

Comment: Just to reiterate: I do not think the problem is with the trigger but rather elsewhere in your code, the new trigger logic may simply be highlighting it. We will need more code to see where the problem may be.